# Auto re-sizable div that maintains a height ratio respectively to its parent

Tags: html, css

Say you have a `div (A)` and a `div (B)`. `div (A)` is the parent, and has `height: auto`. `div (B)` also has `height: auto`. What I would like to know (if even possible without .js), is how to keep `div (B)` at say, 90% height of `div (A)`. Any and all responses are appreciated.

**EDIT**
I guess I should have mentioned, the reason for needing an expanding div inside a div is because I wanted to have content within the child div that expands as more content is added. As the child is expanding, I would like the parent to expand as well, all while staying a uniform distance from the inner div.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not without JavaScript

Say `div (A)` has a some text (so that it has an automatically calculated height) and its current height is `x`. If `div (B)` were then to have a height of `y` where `y == x*0.9` then `div (A)` would no longer be tall enough to hold `div (B)` because its height would now need to be `x+x*0.9`. This is a circular definition as far as I can tell

**Edit**: Here is something that maintains 90% proportions with just CSS under the conditions that `divA` and `divB` are both parents to some other `div` rather than `divA` being a parent to `divB` (`height:300px` is arbitrary as are the `width`s):

```
<!--
    a = 0.52631579, b = 0.47368421
    a + b = 1.0
    b/a = 0.9 (roughly)
-->
<div style="background:#f00; width:150px; height:300px;">
    <div id="divA" style="background:#0f0; width:100px; height:52.631579%"></div>
    <div id="divB" style="background:#00f; width:100px; height:47.368421%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But not something that cannot fulfilled with javascript, correct?

Comment: I would imagine that you would use JavaScript to get the `offsetHeight` of `div (A)`, assign that value plus 90% to `div (A)`, and assign the `offsetHeight` times 90% to `div (B)`

Comment: Thanks again. Also, I made a typo in the above comment. It was supposed to state "WITHOUT javascript."